# Formal proof method for predicate logics

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I am looking for the official name for a proof method,
The method consists of proving the INconsistency of a theory.
This was done using trees. We call it classic-elimination method but I don't know if it is the "official" name.

Does someone know?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for [Truth Trees](https://legacy.earlham.edu/~peters/courses/log/treeprop.htm) or [Semantic Tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux)

(same method ... different names)

Here is a [nice website](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) that creates the trees automatically ... unfortunately it does not have identity.